# ES6 extends static function in parent class

Tags: javascript, node.js, activerecord, typescript

I trying write a ActiveRecord class in ES6. But I have problem with inheritance of static function.

```
class ActiveRecord {
    static tableName() {
       this.name
    }

    static findById(id) {
       // read from database balabala, need tableName
       console.log(this.tableName())
    }
}

class Contact extends ActiveRecord {

    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    static tableName() {
        return 'contact'
    }
}

Contact.findById(1) // got "ActiveRecord", I need it to be "contact" but it didn't work that way
```

I think i rewrite the static tableName function, but findById didn't call tableName function of Contact. My question is how can I call tableName of Contact rather than tableName of ActiveRecord?

Comment: Which Node version are you using? I get `contact` has output. The code seems fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript es6 override static properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103053/javascript-es6-override-static-properties)

Comment: I'm working on hybrid app, use angualr 2 with typescript, run in desktop browser

Comment: Then maybe your transpiler has bugs.

Comment: @mortezaT: Don't see how that's a duplicate.

Comment: Works for me as well with TS 1.8.10. What version of TypeScript are you using (`tsc -v`)?