# Simulate long-press, long tab in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement audio recording in React.
The best free library I could find for this was:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mp3-recorder

But the library only exposes a button that you have to long-press while recording. This is not what I want. I want a start-recording and end-recording button. Now I'm trying to find the easiest way around this. One idea is to simply simulate the long-press event with react/JS.

Is that at all possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say mocking the event is the best way to do this, but to answer the question directly: yes, you could mock the event.

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isRecording: false
    }
    this.myClick = this.myClick.bind(this)
  }
  myClick () {
    let recorder = document.getElementById('recorder').childNodes[0].childNodes[0]
    if (this.state.isRecording) {
      let pressStart = new Event('mousedown')
      pressStart.target = recorder
      this.setState({isRecording:true}, () => window.dispatchEvent(pressStart))
    }
    else {
      let pressEnd = newEvent('mouseup')
      pressEnd.target = recorder
      this.setState({isRecording:false}, () => window.dispatchEvent(pressEnd))
    }
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <section>
        <button onClick={this.myClick}>Start/Stop</button>
        <div id='recorder'>
          <Recorder />
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

You would have to hide the default record button with css `display:none` so that it can't pick up the actual mousedown and mouseup events.

I would actually recommend trying to extend the Recorder component and overwrite the render, but I have not been able to do this successfully yet:

```
// example, not fully-functional snippet
class MyRecorder extends Recorder {
  render () {
    return (
      <button></button>
    )
  }
}
```

You can see from their [code](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/react-mp3-recorder/blob/master/src/index.js) that they have `_onMouseDown` and `_onMouseUp` functions that you could work with.

Extending the Recorder component isn't fool-proof, you'd possibly run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103053/javascript-es6-override-static-properties), but it seems that modern browsers would accept it.